# Where can I find recent changes of my favorites?

Tags: support, bookmarks, favorites-notifications

Ok, I don't want to debate UI changes here, but there's one thing I can't find back: when I click on the arrow, the popup shows me that there are a number of changes in questions I favorited:

[image]

But when I click on 'favorites', I get a complete list of marked questions, not only of those that changed (let alone a list that shows me what those changes involve).

Where can I find such a page nowadays?

Answer (score 5):

For now, the old page (https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/?tab=favorites) still works; it's just not linked to.

Comment: Thanks, but IMHO the developers should provide such a page in the new interface, too.

Comment: Perhaps they will. As Jeff said, two devs are going to be working on nothing but the new interface for the next four business days, minimum.